# Pyautogui how to click radio buttons

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I am working on trying to automate the installation of software for a work project. I want to do this in python, then convert it to an exe. Removing the need for installing Python on the virtual machines that are the target for installation.

I am at the beginning stages. I can start the exe, I can now click the Next button(code below) and I can not find a way to click a radio button, here or on google. So I could use X,Y coordinates, but can't find a tool for that.

Here is the code I have:

```
import pyautogui as py
import os
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.Popen('C:\Program Files (x86)\Path\to\My.exe')
#py.PAUSE = 2.5
time.sleep(5)

#py.hotkey('alt', 'N')
py.keyDown('alt')
py.keyDown('n')
py.keyUp('n')
py.keyUp('alt')

#py.press('enter')
#py.hotkey('alt', 'N')
#py.press('enter')
#py.click('Next', clicks=1, interval=1)
```

If someone can share, or point me to docs, other than the pyautogui docs as they did not help imho, I would be very appreciative.

And if anyone has automated software installs, with clicking Next, radio buttons, dropdown lists etc, any/all pointers would be great as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get X, Y coordinates use

```
pyautogui.position()
```

which is documented [HERE](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html). To make your own utility, you could do:

```
while True:
    print(pyautogui.position())
```

and just kill the Python program after you have extracted your coordinates.

To control windows (and only in Windows) you can use the hard-to-find [`getwindow`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/roadmap.html?highlight=getwindow) function.

For your application, I would recommend trying to figure out what the keypresses are. X,Y coordinates seems prone to error. To navigate a form with the keyboard and press buttons, ALT+, arrow keys, space bar, TAB, and ENTER are typically used.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was worried about using X,Y coordinates. I was asking because my code above is klunky. I tried using Alt N for Next but it would not take. I will experiment with other keys!!

Comment: Hello, I am not able to use some keys like Tab. I had hoped I could tab over to the radio button in question then send an Enter to select it. I have to do a Mouse Click of some kind. I am going through the docs and researching this. If you have any thoughts I would appreciate them!

Comment: [Docs are here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) for keystrokes. `pyautogui.hotkey('tab')` should send a TAB keystroke. If that is not working, then probably the target window is not active. For that use `fw = pyautogui.getWindow(<title>)` and `fw.activate()`. A great tutorial for pyautogui is [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/).